# Can Marginal effects and Incidence Rate Ratios be exactly the same?

Tags: r, regression, count-data, marginal-effect, incidence-rate-ratio

Consider a boring count data model of citations of an article in relation to its page number and the price of the journal. I prefer an ordinary negative binomial regression.

Can it be that the marginal effects and the incidence rate ratios are *exactly* the same?

To showcase my problem using the [`mfx` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mfx/mfx.pdf) for `R`:

```
library("AER")
library("mfx")

data("Journals", package="AER")
mod1 = negbinmfx(citations ~ price + pages,
                 data = Journals)
summary(mod1$fit)

mod2 = negbinirr(citations ~ price + pages,
                 data = Journals)
summary(mod2$fit)
```

In both cases the output is:

```
Call:
glm.nb(formula = formula, data = data, start = NULL, control = control, 
    x = T, init.theta = 1.122237885, link = log)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.0940  -1.0478  -0.5337   0.2689   4.1997  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  4.6420980  0.1518096  30.578  < 2e-16 ***
price       -0.0006530  0.0002105  -3.102  0.00192 ** 
pages        0.0020846  0.0001859  11.212  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(1.1222) family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 356.92  on 179  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 204.64  on 177  degrees of freedom
AIC: 2561.2

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1


              Theta:  1.122 
          Std. Err.:  0.106 

 2 x log-likelihood:  -2553.175
```

Using a Poisson model instead of a NegBin model poses the same question. However, I do find difference between the marginal effects of a Probit model and its ORR version, as in the [other documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mfx/vignettes/mfxarticle.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this riddle is simple: `$fit` does not contain what I was looking for. It contains the parameters of the model that `mfx()` wraps.

To see this, the output of `mod1` is

```
Call:
negbinmfx(formula = citations ~ price + pages, data = Journals)

Marginal Effects:
          dF/dx Std. Err.       z     P>|z|    
price -0.289655  0.095566 -3.0309  0.002438 ** 
pages  0.924638  0.105027  8.8038 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

and the output of `mod2` is

````
Call:
negbinirr(formula = citations ~ price + pages, data = Journals)

Incidence-Rate Ratio:
             IRR  Std. Err.       z   P>|z|    
price 0.99934719 0.00021036 -3.1023 0.00192 ** 
pages 1.00208677 0.00018631 11.2123 < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```
````